# Verificar usuário

Tags: javascript

Quero que quando o usuário entrar se logar em minha página, o javascript verifica o perfil dele no sistema e se o perfil estiver vazio, ele direciona para a página inicial.

É simples, estou tentando esse código aqui, mas não está funcionando direito:

```
<script>

  var perfil = document.querySelector('#perfil').textContent;

  if (perfil = ''){

  window.location = "../index.php";
  }
</script>
```

É só isso que eu preciso fazer, se perfil receber vazio, então vá para a index, só que não está funcionando desse jeito aí, como posso fazer?

Meu html

Comment: Poderia postar o html?

Comment: o html? o html é só uma tag p com id perfil. na verdade não vejo a necessidade de postar. mas é assim. <p id="perfil"></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var perfil = document.querySelector('#perfil').textContent;
   if (perfil == '') { //seu erro está aqui vc está usando atribuição e não comparação
   window.location.assign("../index.php");
}
```

Comment: Não verdade não é só isso, já tentei comparando também, com ==, mas também não funciona

Comment: Editei a resposta. Tente agora.

Comment: coloquei o assign, mesmo assim não funciona, tipo, quando eu forço a entrada pela url e não tem usuário logado, não acontece nada, ele é direcionado para a index

Comment: Então tinha que ver o html como está.

Comment: O ideal é você debugar sua aplicação no navegador e vê como a variável perfil está vindo e só assim fazer um tratamento nela. Para esclarecer mais suas dúvida: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515349/4312593

Comment: Mas eu já fiz, tenho como ver aqui até sem usar o log, o problema não é esse, só não redireciona mesmo, não sei porque.

Comment: coloquei o html lá #Leandro

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz insira então:  window.location.href = 'sua_url.php'

Comment: Deu certo aí man?